# Jackson Deserializing an array of objects into an array list

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following JSON file to deserialize

```
{
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "USER_ID": 001,
            "COMMISSION": 0,
            "SWAPS": -1.87,
            "PROFIT": -73.39,
            "COMMENT": "MAM|12345678|10020031"
        },
        {
            "USER_ID": 002,
            "COMMISSION": 0,
            "SWAPS": 0,
            "PROFIT": 12.23,
            "COMMENT": "PAMM|12345678|10229501"
        },
        {
            "USER_ID": 003,
            "COMMISSION": 0,
            "SWAPS": 0,
            "PROFIT": 396.77,
            "COMMENT": "PAMM|12345678|10229501"
        },      
...
]}
```

I would like to deserialise the JSON file to something like an ArrayList so that I can calculate individual user's total profit by accessing a value of the array.

I have the following class as a wrapper;

```
Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "rows"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Rows {

    @JsonProperty("rows")
    private ArrayList<Row> rows = null;

    @JsonProperty("rows")
    public ArrayList<Row> getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    @JsonProperty("rows")
    public void setRows(ArrayList<Row> rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }
```

I also have the following class to store each attribute.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "USER_ID",
        "COMMISSION",
        "SWAPS",
        "PROFIT",
        "COMMENT"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Row {
    @JsonProperty("USER_ID")
    private int userId;
    @JsonProperty("COMMISSION")
    private float commission;
    @JsonProperty("SWAPS")
    private float swaps;
    @JsonProperty("PROFIT")
    private float profit;
    @JsonProperty("COMMENT")
    private String comment;

    @JsonProperty("USER_ID")
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("USER_ID")
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("COMMISSION")
    public float getCommission() {
        return commission;
    }
//..setter/getter continue..
```

Finally, I have the following code in my main at the moment. However, it just stores the array of the objects as a whole and I cannot access an individual attribute of the row.
The size of the array is just 1 and every data is in it.

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);


ArrayList<Rows> rowsArrayList = mapper.readValue(new File(ClientsRecordsPath), ArrayList.class);

            //json array to array object
            System.out.println("JSON array to Array objects...");
            System.out.println(rowsArrayList.get(0));
```

Output:

```
COMMENT=PAMM|123456|10314558}, {USER_ID=001, COMMISSION=0, SWAPS=0, PROFIT=13.57, COMMENT=PAMM|123456|10314558}, {USER_ID=002, COMMISSION=0, SWAPS=0, PROFIT=67.47, COMMENT=PAMM|123456|10314558}, {USER_ID=003, COMMISSION=0, SWAPS=0, PROFIT=202.41, COMMENT=PAMM|123456|10314558}, {USER_ID=004, COMMISSION=0, SWAPS=0, PROFIT=58.96, COMMENT=PAMM|123456|10314558}, {USER_ID=005, COMMISSION=0, SWAPS=0, PROFIT=6095, COMMENT=PAMM|123456|10314560}, {USER_ID=006, COMMISSION=0, ....
```

How can I store each user's data into an array list and access it individually so that I can calculate the individual's total profit?

Comment: ```Rows rows = mapper.readValue(new File(ClientsRecordsPath), Rows.class);``` will produce correct result, no?
Do you have one entry of 'Rows' object in your JSON file or many?

Probably `TypeReference` may be useful here: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that leading zeroes are not allowed, so this JSON will be invalid. We can use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to check this.

Also, `ObjectMapper` throws `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed`.

After removing leading zeroes, you can do:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

Rows rowsArrayList = mapper.readValue(new File(ClientsRecordsPath), Rows.class);
```

Output:

```
JSON array to Array objects...
Row(userId=1, commission=0.0, swaps=-1.87, profit=-73.39, comment=MAM|12345678|10020031)
Row(userId=2, commission=0.0, swaps=0.0, profit=12.23, comment=PAMM|12345678|10229501)
Row(userId=3, commission=0.0, swaps=0.0, profit=396.77, comment=PAMM|12345678|10229501)
```

---

While that works fine, **I suggest to remove the wrapper class if it has no use**.
We can deserialize straight to a `List<Row>`:

```
List<Row> rows = Arrays.asList(mapper.treeToValue(mapper.readTree(new File(ClientsRecordsPath)).get("rows"), Row[].class));
rows.forEach(System.out::println);

Row(userId=1, commission=0.0, swaps=-1.87, profit=-73.39, comment=MAM|12345678|10020031)
Row(userId=2, commission=0.0, swaps=0.0, profit=12.23, comment=PAMM|12345678|10229501)
Row(userId=3, commission=0.0, swaps=0.0, profit=396.77, comment=PAMM|12345678|10229501)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I would need to create a wrapper class for this JSON structure... but It looks like I don't.

Answer (score 0):

The code for parsing the json file will be:

```
Rows rows = mapper.readValue(new File(ClientsRecordsPath), Rows.class);
```

as the root of json is represented by Rows class, not ArrayList